# Multi-threading technique taking longer than single thread C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've created a C# console application where a user can enter a number of any size and then allows the user the option to choose how they would like the program to find out what the number is - using single core or multi-core.

The program seems to work fine, yet testing say an exact figure of 10,000,000 using both options seems to yield a longer duration for the multi-threading option. Can someone shed some light on this.

**UPDATE**:

After spending some time looking into this and following the accepted answer, I implemented significant changes that involved intensive computations during iterations of a counter variable that push the processor to determine a number entered. In this case, a multithreading operation yields a significant improvement in speed.

Revised code is as follows that was based on a WPF application:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace C_Sharp_Programming_Portfolio
    {
    public partial class Multithreading : Page
    {
        /* Variable declarations */
        static string numberTextToEncrypt;
        static double numberDoubleToEncrypt;
        static bool areaCodeCheck;
        static int areaCodeLength;
        static int noCores;
        static double[] from = new Double[Environment.ProcessorCount];
        static double[] to = new Double[Environment.ProcessorCount];
        static string areaConfirmed;
        static string completionTime;
        static string coresUsed;
        static string correctNumber;
        static string numberTextToDecrypt;
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        /* Stores the divisible number following dividing the telephone number by the number of cores */
        static double valuePerThread;

        /* Stores the divisible number following dividing the telephone number by the number of cores, later
        used for setting the values for each core to check telephone number entered*/
        static double difference;

        /* Create two read only arrays and store area codes and region names */
        static readonly double[] areaCodes = { 0113, 0114, 0115, 0116, 0117, 0118, 01200, 01202, 01204, 01205, 01206, 01207, 01208, 01209, 0121, 01223, 01224, 01225, 01226, 01227, 01228, 01229, 01233, 01234, 01235, 01236, 01237, 01239, 01241, 01242, 01243, 01244, 01245, 01246, 01248, 01249, 01250, 01252, 01253, 01254, 01255, 01256, 01257, 01258, 01259, 01260, 01261, 01262, 01263, 01264, 01267, 01268, 01269, 01270, 01271, 01273, 01274, 01275, 01276, 01277, 01278, 01279, 01280, 01282, 01283, 01284, 01285, 01286, 01287, 01288, 01289, 01290, 01291, 01292, 01293, 01294, 01295, 01296, 01297, 01298, 01299, 01300, 01301, 01302, 01303, 01304, 01305, 01306, 01307, 01308, 01309, 0131, 01320, 01322, 01323, 01324, 01325, 01326, 01327, 01328, 01329, 01330, 01332, 01333, 01334, 01335, 01337, 01339, 01340, 01341, 01342, 01343, 01344, 01346, 01347, 01348, 01349, 01350, 01352, 01353, 01354, 01355, 01356, 01357, 01358, 01359, 01360, 01361, 01362, 01363, 01364, 01366, 01367, 01368, 01369, 01371, 01372, 01373, 01375, 01376, 01377, 01379, 01380, 01381, 01382, 01383, 01384, 01386, 01387, 013873, 01388, 01389, 01392, 01394, 01395, 01397, 01398, 01400, 01403, 01404, 01405, 01406, 01407, 01408, 01409, 0141, 01420, 01422, 01423, 01424, 01425, 01427, 01428, 01429, 01430, 01431, 01432, 01433, 01434, 01435, 01436, 01437, 01438, 01439, 01440, 01442, 01443, 01444, 01445, 01446, 01449, 01450, 01451, 01452, 01453, 01454, 01455, 01456, 01457, 01458, 01460, 01461, 01462, 01463, 01464, 01465, 01466, 01467, 01469, 01470, 01471, 01472, 01473, 01474, 01475, 01476, 01477, 01478, 01479, 01480, 01481, 01482, 01483, 01484, 01485, 01487, 01488, 01489, 01490, 01491, 01492, 01493, 01494, 01495, 01496, 01497, 01499, 01501, 01502, 01503, 01505, 01506, 01507, 01508, 01509, 0151, 01520, 01522, 01524, 015242, 01525, 01526, 01527, 01528, 01529, 01530, 01531, 01534, 01535, 01536, 01538, 01539, 015394, 015395, 015396, 01540, 01542, 01543, 01544, 01545, 01546, 01547, 01548, 01549, 01550, 01553, 01554, 01555, 01556, 01557, 01558, 01559, 01560, 01561, 01562, 01563, 01564, 01565, 01566, 01567, 01568, 01569, 01570, 01571, 01572, 01573, 01575, 01576, 01577, 01578, 01579, 01580, 01581, 01582, 01583, 01584, 01586, 01588, 01590, 01591, 01592, 01593, 01594, 01595, 01597, 01598, 01599, 01600, 01603, 01604, 01606, 01608, 01609, 0161, 01620, 01621, 01622, 01623, 01624, 01625, 01626, 01628, 01629, 01630, 01631, 01633, 01634, 01635, 01636, 01637, 01638, 01639, 01641, 01642, 01643, 01644, 01646, 01647, 01650, 01651, 01652, 01653, 01654, 01655, 01656, 01659, 01661, 01663, 01664, 01665, 01666, 01667, 01668, 01669, 01670, 01671, 01672, 01673, 01674, 01675, 01676, 01677, 01678, 01680, 01681, 01683, 01684, 01685, 01686, 01687, 01688, 01689, 01690, 01691, 01692, 01694, 01695, 01697, 016973, 016974, 016977, 01698, 01700, 01702, 01704, 01706, 01707, 01708, 01709, 01720, 01721, 01722, 01723, 01724, 01725, 01726, 01727, 01728, 01729, 01730, 01732, 01733, 01736, 01737, 01738, 01740, 01743, 01744, 01745, 01746, 01747, 01748, 01749, 01750, 01751, 01752, 01753, 01754, 01756, 01757, 01758, 01759, 01760, 01761, 01763, 01764, 01765, 01766, 01767, 01768, 017683, 017684, 017687, 01769, 01770, 01771, 01772, 01773, 01775, 01776, 01777, 01778, 01779, 01780, 01782, 01784, 01785, 01786, 01787, 01788, 01789, 01790, 01792, 01793, 01794, 01795, 01796, 01797, 01798, 01799, 01803, 01805, 01806, 01807, 01808, 01809, 01821, 01822, 01823, 01824, 01825, 01827, 01828, 01829, 01830, 01832, 01833, 01834, 01835, 01837, 01838, 01840, 01841, 01842, 01843, 01844, 01845, 01847, 01848, 01851, 01852, 01854, 01855, 01856, 01857, 01858, 01859, 01862, 01863, 01864, 01865, 01866, 01869, 01870, 01871, 01872, 01873, 01874, 01875, 01876, 01877, 01878, 01879, 01880, 01882, 01883, 01884, 01885, 01886, 01887, 01888, 01889, 01890, 01892, 01895, 01896, 01899, 01900, 01902, 01903, 01904, 01905, 01908, 01909, 0191, 01920, 01922, 01923, 01924, 01925, 01926, 01928, 01929, 01931, 01932, 01933, 01934, 01935, 01937, 01938, 01939, 01942, 01943, 01944, 01945, 01946, 019467, 01947, 01948, 01949, 01950, 01951, 01952, 01953, 01954, 01955, 01957, 01959, 01962, 01963, 01964, 01967, 01968, 01969, 01970, 01971, 01972, 01974, 01975, 01977, 01978, 01980, 01981, 01982, 01983, 01984, 01985, 01986, 01987, 01988, 01989, 01992, 01993, 01994, 01995, 01997, 020, 023, 024, 028, 029 };
        static readonly string[] regions = { "Leeds", "Sheffield", "Nottingham", "Leicester", "Bristol", "Reading", "Clitheroe", "Bournemouth", "Bolton", "Boston", "Colchester", "Consett", "Bodmin", "Redruth", "Birmingham", "Cambridge", "Aberdeen", "Bath", "Barnsley", "Canterbury", "Carlisle", "Barrow-in Furness / Millom", "Ashford (Kent)", "Bedford", "Abingdon", "Coatbridge", "Bideford", "Cardigan", "Arbroath", "Cheltenham", "Chichester", "Chester", "Chelmsford", "Chesterfield", "Bangor (Gwynedd)", "Chippenham", "Blairgowrie", "Aldershot", "Blackpool", "Blackburn", "Clacton-on-Sea", "Basingstoke", "Coppull", "Blandford", "Alloa", "Congleton", "Banff", "Bridlington", "Cromer", "Andover", "Carmarthen", "Basildon", "Ammanford", "Crewe", "Barnstaple", "Brighton", "Bradford", "Clevedon", "Camberley", "Brentwood", "Bridgwater", "Bishops Stortford", "Buckingham", "Burnley", "Burton-on-Trent", "Bury-St-Edmunds", "Cirencester", "Caernarfon", "Guisborough", "Bude", "Berwick-on-Tweed", "Cumnock", "Chepstow", "Ayr", "Crawley", "Ardrossan", "Banbury", "Aylesbury", "Axminster", "Buxton", "Bewdley", "Cerne Abbas", "Arrochar", "Doncaster", "Folkestone", "Dover", "Dorchester", "Dorking", "Forfar", "Bridport", "Forres", "Edinburgh", "Fort Augustus", "Dartford", "Eastbourne", "Falkirk", "Darlington", "Falmouth", "Daventry", "Fakenham", "Fareham", "Banchory", "Derby", "Anstruther", "St Andrews", "Ashbourne", "Ladybank", "Aboyne / Ballater", "Craigellachie", "Barmouth", "East Grinstead", "Elgin", "Bracknell", "Fraserburgh", "Easingwold", "Fishguard", "Dingwall", "Dunkeld", "Mold", "Ely", "Chatteris", "East Kilbride", "Brechin", "Strathaven", "Ellon", "Pakenham", "Killearn", "Duns", "Dereham", "Crediton", "Ashburton", "Downham Market", "Faringdon", "Dunbar", "Dunoon", "Great Dunmow", "Esher", "Frome", "Grays Thurrock", "Braintree", "Driffield", "Diss", "Devizes", "Fortrose", "Dundee", "Dunfermline", "Dudley", "Evesham", "Dumfries", "Langholm", "Bishop Auckland / Stanhope", "Dumbarton", "Exeter", "Felixstowe", "Budleigh Salterton", "Fort William", "Dulverton", "Honington", "Horsham", "Honiton", "Goole", "Holbeach", "Holyhead", "Golspie", "Holsworthy", "Glasgow", "Alton", "Halifax", "Boroughbridge / Harrogate", "Hastings", "Ringwood", "Gainsborough", "Haslemere", "Hartlepool", "Market Weighton / North Cave", "Helmsdale", "Hereford", "Hathersage", "Bellingham / Haltwhistle / Hexham", "Heathfield", "Helensburgh", "Clynderwen / Haverfordwest", "Stevenage", "Helmsley", "Haverhill", "Hemel Hempstead", "Pontypridd", "Haywards Heath", "Gairloch", "Barry", "Stowmarket", "Hawick", "Stow-on-the-Wold", "Gloucester", "Dursley", "Chipping Sodbury", "Hinckley", "Glenurquhart", "Glossop", "Glastonbury", "Chard", "Gretna", "Hitchin", "Inverness", "Insch", "Girvan", "Huntly", "Inverurie", "Killingholme", "Isle of Skye – Edinbane", "Isle of Skye – Broadford", "Grimsby", "Ipswich", "Gravesend", "Greenock", "Grantham", "Holmes Chapel", "Isle of Skye – Portree", "Grantown-on-Spey", "Huntingdon", "Guernsey", "Hull", "Guildford", "Huddersfield", "Hunstanton", "Warboys", "Hungerford", "Bishops Waltham", "Corwen", "Henley-on-Thames", "Colwyn Bay", "Great Yarmouth", "High Wycombe", "Pontypool", "Islay and Jura", "Hay-on-Wye", "Inveraray", "Harthill", "Lowestoft", "Looe", "Johnstone", "Bathgate", "Alford (Lincs) / Louth / Horncastle", "Brooke", "Loughborough", "Liverpool", "Lochcarron", "Lincoln", "Lancaster", "Hornby", "Leighton Buzzard", "Martin", "Redditch", "Laggan", "Sleaford", "Coalville", "Ledbury", "Jersey", "Keighley", "Kettering", "Leek", "Kendal", "Hawkshead", "Grange-Over-Sands", "Sedbergh", "Kingussie", "Keith", "Cannock", "Kington", "Llanarth", "Lochgilphead", "Knighton", "Kingsbridge", "Lairg", "Llandovery", "Kings Lynn", "Llanelli", "Lanark", "Castle Douglas", "Kirkcudbright", "Llandeilo", "Llandysul", "Moscow", "Laurencekirk", "Kidderminster", "Kilmarnock", "Lapworth", "Knutsford", "Launceston", "Killin", "Leominster", "Stonehaven", "Lampeter", "Lochinver", "Oakham", "Kelso", "Kirriemuir", "Lockerbie", "Kinross", "Lauder", "Liskeard", "Cranbrook", "New Luce", "Luton", "Carradale", "Ludlow", "Campbeltown", "Bishops Castle", "Lymington", "Llanwrtyd Wells", "Kirkcaldy", "Lybster", "Lydney", "Lerwick, Shetland Islands", "Llandrindod Wells", "Lynton", "Kyle", "Monmouth", "Norwich", "Northampton", "Northwich", "Chipping Norton", "Northallerton", "Manchester", "North Berwick", "Maldon", "Maidstone", "Mansfield", "Isle of Man", "Macclesfield", "Newton Abbot", "Maidenhead", "Matlock", "Market Drayton", "Oban", "Newport", "Medway", "Newbury", "Newark", "Newquay", "Newmarket", "Neath", "Strathy", "Middlesbrough", "Minehead", "New Galloway", "Milford Haven", "Moretonhampstead", "Cemmaes Road", "Oldmeldrum", "Brigg", "Malton", "Machynlleth", "Maybole", "Bridgend", "Sanquhar", "Prudhoe", "New Mills", "Melton Mowbray", "Alnwick", "Malmesbury", "Nairn", "Bamburgh", "Rothbury", "Morpeth", "Newton Stewart", "Marlborough", "Market Rasen", "Montrose", "Coleshill", "Meriden", "Bedale", "Bala", "Isle of Mull – Craignure", "Isle of Mull – Fionnphort", "Moffat", "Malvern", "Merthyr Tydfil", "Llanidloes / Newtown", "Mallaig", "Isle of Mull – Tobermory", "Orpington", "Betws-y-Coed", "Oswestry", "North Walsham", "Church Stretton", "Skelmersdale", "Brampton (6 figure numbers)", "Wigton", "Raughton Head", "Brampton (4 and 5 figure numbers)", "Motherwell", "Rothesay", "Southend-on-Sea", "Southport", "Rochdale", "Welwyn Garden City", "Romford", "Rotherham", "Isles of Scilly", "Peebles", "Salisbury", "Scarborough", "Scunthorpe", "Rockbourne", "St Austell", "St Albans", "Saxmundham", "Settle", "Petersfield", "Sevenoaks", "Peterborough", "Penzance", "Redhill", "Perth", "Sedgefield", "Shrewsbury", "St Helens", "Rhyl", "Bridgnorth", "Shaftesbury", "Richmond", "Shepton Mallet", "Selkirk", "Pickering", "Plymouth", "Slough", "Skegness", "Skipton", "Selby", "Pwllheli", "Pocklington", "Swaffham", "Temple Cloud", "Royston", "Crieff", "Ripon", "Porthmadog", "Sandy", "Penrith", "Appleby", "Pooley Bridge", "Keswick", "South Molton", "Isle of Arran", "Maud", "Preston", "Ripley", "Spalding", "Stranraer", "Retford", "Bourne", "Peterhead", "Stamford", "Stoke-on-Trent", "Staines", "Stafford", "Stirling", "Sudbury", "Rugby", "Stratford-upon-Avon", "Spilsby", "Swansea", "Swindon", "Romsey", "Sittingbourne", "Pitlochry", "Rye", "Pulborough", "Saffron Walden", "Torquay", "Torrington", "Sullom Voe, Shetland Islands", "Ballindalloch", "Tomatin", "Tomdoun", "Kinrossie", "Tavistock", "Taunton", "Ruthin", "Uckfield", "Tamworth", "Coupar Angus", "Tarporley", "Kirkwhelpington", "Clopton", "Barnard Castle", "Narberth", "St Boswells", "Okehampton", "Dalmally", "Camelford", "Padstow", "Thetford", "Thanet", "Thame", "Thirsk", "Thurso / Tongue", "Thornhill", "Lewis and Great Bernera, Outer Hebrides", "Kilmelford", "Ullapool", "Ballachulish", "Orkney", "Sanday", "Market Harborough", "Harris, Outer Hebrides", "Tain", "Ardgay", "Abington", "Oxford", "Kilchrenan", "Bicester", "Benebecula, Outer Hebrides", "Barra, Outer Hebrides", "Truro", "Abergavenny", "Brecon", "Tranent", "North Uist, Outer Hebrides", "Callander", "South Uist, Outer Hebrides", "Scarinish", "Tarbert", "Kinloch Rannoch", "Caterham", "Tiverton", "Bromyard", "Knightwick", "Aberfeldy", "Turriff", "Rugeley", "Ayton / Coldstream", "Tunbridge Wells", "Uxbridge", "Galashiels", "Biggar", "Workington", "Wolverhampton", "Worthing", "York", "Worcester", "Milton Keynes", "Worksop", "Tyneside / Durham / Sunderland", "Ware", "Walsall", "Watford", "Wakefield", "Warrington", "Warwick", "Runcorn", "Wareham", "Shap", "Weybridge", "Wellingborough", "Weston-Super-Mare", "Yeovil", "Wetherby", "Welshpool", "Wem", "Wigan", "Guiseley", "West Heslerton", "Wisbech", "Whitehaven", "Gosforth", "Whitby", "Whitchurch", "Whatton", "Sandwick, Shetland Islands", "Colonsay", "Telford", "Wymondham", "Madingley", "Wick", "Mid Yell, Shetland Islands", "Westerham", "Winchester", "Wincanton", "Hornsea / Patrington", "Strontian", "Penicuik", "Leyburn", "Aberystwyth", "Scourie", "Glenborrodale", "Llanon", "Alford (Aberdeen) / Strathdon", "Pontefract", "Wrexham", "Amesbury", "Wormbridge", "Builth Wells", "Isle of Wight", "Watchet", "Warminster", "Bungay", "Ebbsfleet", "Wigtown", "Ross-on-Wye", "Lea Valley", "Witney", "St Clears", "Garstang", "Strathpeffer", "London", "Southampton / Portsmouth", "Coventry", "Northern Ireland", "Cardiff" };

        /* Set up the Multithreading class */
        public Multithreading()
        {
            /* Set up Multithreading component */
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /* Button function to encrypt the telephone number entered */
        void ButtonEncrypt(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            numberTextToEncrypt = null;
            numberDoubleToEncrypt = 0; // Set variable to zero
            areaCodeCheck = false; // Set variable to false
            NumberFound.Text = "#"; // Reset text block value
            Region.Text = "#"; // Reset text block value
            EncryptionTime.Text = "#"; // Set text block value
            CoresUsed.Text = "#"; // Set text block value
            NumberEncryptionTextBox.Text = null; // Set text block value to null
            numberTextToEncrypt = NumberToEncrypt.Text; // Set variable equal to text box text
            numberTextToEncrypt = Regex.Replace(numberTextToEncrypt, @"\s+", ""); // Remove white space entered
            /* Check if variable length is equal to 11 digits */
            if (numberTextToEncrypt.Length == 11)
            {
                /* Try to convert the variable to double */
                if (double.TryParse(numberTextToEncrypt, out numberDoubleToEncrypt))
                {
                    /* Invoke function to verify the area code entered matches an area */
                    verifyAreaCode();
                    /* Check the area code entered matches an area */
                    if (areaCodeCheck)
                    {
                        watch.Reset(); // Reset stopwatch
                        watch.Start(); // Start stopwatch
                        progressBarValueEncrypt.IsIndeterminate = true; // Invoke progress bar
                        NumberFound.Text = "[PROCESSING]"; // Set text block value
                        EncryptionTime.Text = "[PROCESSING]"; // Set text block value
                        CoresUsed.Text = "[PROCESSING]"; // Set text block value
                        Region.Text = "[PROCESSING]"; // Set text block value
                        BackgroundWorker inBackground = new BackgroundWorker(); // Create background worker method
                        inBackground.DoWork += doWork; // Invoke 'doWork' method
                        inBackground.RunWorkerCompleted += onCompletion; // Invoke 'onCompletion' method once work is completed
                        inBackground.RunWorkerAsync(); // Run background worker asynchronously
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* Display error message and return command to the user interface */
                        MessageBox.Show("Please ensure a valid UK area code is entered", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    /* Display error message and return command to the user interface */
                    MessageBox.Show("Please ensure only a number is entered", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                /* Display error message and return command to the user interface */
                MessageBox.Show("Please ensure a valid telephone number is entered containing 11 digits", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }

        }

        /* Function to carry out work in background worker thread */
        void doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            valuePerThread = 0; // Initialise the variable to zero
            difference = 0; // Initialise the variable to zero
            areaCodeCheck = false; // Initialise variable to false
            areaCodeLength = 0; // Set area code length to zero
            noCores = Environment.ProcessorCount; // Get number of cores and store in variable
            Thread[] multiThreads = new Thread[noCores]; // Create array of threads equal to number of cores

            /* Check to see if the telephone number is divisible by the number of cores */
            if (numberDoubleToEncrypt % noCores == 0)
            {
                /* Divide the telephone number entered by the number of cores and store in variable */
                valuePerThread = numberDoubleToEncrypt / noCores;

                /* Divide the telephone number entered by the number of cores and store in new variable,
                in order to determine the increment value to be added */
                difference = numberDoubleToEncrypt / noCores;

                /* Invoke function to set the values to be checked on each core to determine the telephone
                number the user has entered */
                setValues();
            }
            else
            {
                /* Divide the telephone number entered by the number of cores and round up to the nearest
                whole number, followed by storing the value in a variable */
                valuePerThread = Math.Ceiling(numberDoubleToEncrypt / noCores);

                /* Divide the telephone number entered by the number of cores and round up to the nearest
                whole number, followed by storing the value in a new variable in order to determine the
                increment value to be added */
                difference = Math.Ceiling(numberDoubleToEncrypt / noCores);

                /* Invoke function to set the values to be checked on each core to determine the telephone
                number the user has entered */
                setValues();
            }

            /* For the number of cores in the device, execute the following */
            for (int i = 0; i < noCores; i++)
            {
                multiThreads[i] = new Thread(findNumber); // Create a new thread and pass in the 'findNumber' function as a parameter
                multiThreads[i].Start(i); // Invoke the thread and pass in the position to the 'findNumber' function
            }

            /* For the number of cores in the device, wait for each thread to complete its process before
            continuing */
            for (int i = 0; i < noCores; i++) multiThreads[i].Join();

            /* Store the time taken to complete the process in a variable */
            completionTime = Math.Floor(watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString() + " seconds ";
            coresUsed = noCores.ToString(); // Convert the cores used to a string and store in a variable
        }

        /* Function to set the 'from' and 'to' array position values for each core on the device to determine
        the telephone number the user entered */
        void setValues()
        {
            double start = 0; // Declare and initialise the 'start' value to zero
            /* For the number of cores on the device, execute the for loop */
            for (int i = 0; i < noCores; i++)
            {
                from[i] = start; // Store the 'start' value in the 'from' array position
                to[i] = valuePerThread; // Store the 'valuePerThread' value in the 'to' array position
                start += difference; // Increment the 'start' value by the difference
                valuePerThread += difference; // Increment the 'valuePerThread' by the difference
            }
        }

        /* Function to execute from the background worker once the 'doWork' function is completed */
        void onCompletion(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            /* Set text block value and insert a space at the position proceeding the area code length */
            NumberFound.Text = correctNumber.Insert(areaCodeLength, " ");
            Region.Text = areaConfirmed; // Set text block value
            EncryptionTime.Text = completionTime; // Set text block value
            CoresUsed.Text = coresUsed; // Set text block value
            /* Call external class method and pass in variable to encrypt the telephone number entered.
            Set text box text equal to encrypted value */
            NumberEncryptionTextBox.Text = EncryptionDecryption.Encrypt(correctNumber);
            progressBarValueEncrypt.IsIndeterminate = false; // Disable the progress bar
        }

        /* Function to verify the area code matches an area code */
        void verifyAreaCode()
        {
            /* For the length of the 'areaCodes', execute the following loop */
            for (int j = 0; j < areaCodes.Length; j++)
            {
                /* Check if the first four characters of the number to encrypt text matches
                the array position of the area code */
                if (numberTextToEncrypt.Substring(1, 4) == Convert.ToString(areaCodes[j]))
                {
                    areaCodeCheck = true; // Set the variable to true to confirm it matches
                }
                else
                {
                    /* Check if the first three characters of the number to encrypt text matches
                    the array position of the area code */
                    if (numberTextToEncrypt.Substring(1, 3) == Convert.ToString(areaCodes[j]))
                    {
                        areaCodeCheck = true; // Set the variable to true to confirm it matches
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* Check if the first two characters of the number to encrypt text matches
                        the array position of the area code */
                        if (numberTextToEncrypt.Substring(1, 2) == Convert.ToString(areaCodes[j]))
                        {
                            areaCodeCheck = true; // Set the variable to true to confirm it matches
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* Function to find the telephone number entered by the user, passing int the position from the
        calling thread */
        void findNumber(object value)
        {
            /* Declare and initialise the variable set to the position of the calling thread by casting the
            object to an integer */
            int position = (int)value;
            /* Declare and initialise member double value to the 'from' array 'position' value */
            double i = from[position];
            /* Execute while loop to determine if the telephone number entered matches a number between
            the array 'from' position value to the 'to' position value */
            while (i >= from[position] && i <= to[position])
            {
                /* Check if the value matches the telephone number */
                if (i == numberDoubleToEncrypt)
                {
                    /* Set the variable equal to the matching value; convert to string; add a '0' and store
                    in variable */
                    correctNumber = "0" + i.ToString();
                    /* Invoke the find region function and pass in the 'correctNumber' value */
                    findRegion(correctNumber);
                    return; // Return the command to the user interface
                }
                i++; // Increment by one
            }
            return; // Return the command to the user interface
        }

        /* Function to find the region from the telephone number found by the computer */
        void findRegion(string confirmedNumber)
        {
            /* For the length of the 'areaCodes', execute the following loop */
            for (int i = 0; i < areaCodes.Length; i++)
            {
                /* Check if the first four characters of the number to encrypt text matches
                the array position of the area code */
                if (confirmedNumber.Substring(1, 4) == Convert.ToString(areaCodes[i]))
                {
                    areaConfirmed = regions[i]; // Set variable value equal to the 'regions' array position value
                    areaCodeLength = 5; // Set variable value
                }
                else
                {
                    /* Check if the first three characters of the number to encrypt text matches
                    the array position of the area code */
                    if (confirmedNumber.Substring(1, 3) == Convert.ToString(areaCodes[i]))
                    {
                        areaConfirmed = regions[i]; // Set variable value equal to the 'regions' array position value
                        areaCodeLength = 4; // Set variable value
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* Check if the first two characters of the number to encrypt text matches
                        the array position of the area code */
                        if (confirmedNumber.Substring(1, 2) == Convert.ToString(areaCodes[i]))
                        {
                            areaConfirmed = regions[i]; // Set variable value equal to the 'regions' array position value
                            areaCodeLength = 3; // Set variable value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Starting threads comes at a cost. If the work each thread does is light, then the overhead of starting threads gobbles up all the gain your could get in the first place. Try more work for each thread.

Comment: Okay, so maybe adding on a few more extra digits in my case to push the system I guess - is there any existing errors with my current implementation of the code though?

Comment: `while (counter != convertInput) { if (counter == convertInput)`: `if` condition is always `false`.

Comment: Thanks for that - didn't spot it at first!

Comment: @RichardAnsell, how come you deleted all the code from your question? You've removed a lot of the context of the conversations.

Comment: @Adrian, I'm seeing if I can rework the code to make it more efficient instead and then post a re-edit.

Comment: Are you actually creating a sub-divided problem or are you just creating the same problem but handled on a different thread?
If you're simply asking one thread (whichever thread it is) to scan from [0 -> 10,000,000] then it will run in a linear time of O(N).
If you ask two threads to scan - respectively - [0->5,000,000] and [5,000,001->10,000,000] then you will get an improvement as your complexity is O(N/2) due to subdivision of the problem space.

Comment: @Monza, based on my existing code, this will only be the case if I enter a value of 11 or more digits as previously pointed out. The benefits of using extra threads in this case is negated by the simplicity of the execution, which is the reason why I'm going to look at the code shortly to repost a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra performance had from using multiple threads is being displaced by the overhead of starting the thread to begin with. This implementation would be more useful on a more complex instruction.

This unfortunately executes too quickly to benefit from multi threading.

```
while (counter != convertInput)
{
    if (counter == convertInput)
    {
        watch.Stop();
        return;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the message - I've just edited the above code. However, your message above is entirely dependent on the user's actual input, which in my case the user enters a large number such as 10,000,000. This is of course relatively quick to complete, yet any number I enter above this still seems to be quicker on a single thread

Comment: It's still a really fast instruction and not really heavy enough to benefit from being multi-threaded. For example, I had a program that would go through large text files looking for duplicates. These files were sometimes several hundred megabytes in size, but if I gave it a small text file it would actually be slower to use multiple threads.

Comment: Okay, I've done some testing and have noticed that the multi-threading technique in this case is beneficial when at least an 11 digit number is entered, which a value of 1,000,000,000,0 takes 21 seconds to complete. Yet, the same value takes 1 minute 12 seconds on a single thread. Obviously, it would be better to carry some further instruction for either test scenario, which can be implemented to throttle the CPU.

Comment: Exactly, in the example above that is what I ended up doing as well. I also incorporated a merge function that could merge these large text files without introducing duplicates and filter them based on defined parameters.